# why don't work if empty post?

Tags: php

Why don't work $post empty?

```
    if (isset($_GET['profil_refresh'])){
if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
  if (!empty($_POST["fullname"]))
    {echo  "fullname is required";}
// ------------------------
  if (!empty($_POST["email"]))
    {echo  "Email is required";}
// ------------------------
  if (!empty($_POST["fb"]))
    {echo  "varos is required";}
// ------------------------
  if (!empty($_POST["age"]))
    {echo "kor is required";}
// ------------------------
  if (!empty($_POST["aboutme"]))
    {echo "rolad is required";}
}

$loginid = $_SESSION['loginid'];
$hash = $_SESSION['hash'];
$id = $_SESSION['id']; 
$user = $_POST['user'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$fullname = $_POST['fullname'];
$fb = $_POST['fb'];
$age = $_POST['age'];
$aboutme = $_POST['aboutme'];


mysql_query("UPDATE zl SET email='" .$email. "', fullname='" .$fullname. "', 
fb='" .$fb. "', age='" .$age. "', aboutme='" .$aboutme. "', adatok='OK' WHERE loginid='" .$loginid. "'") 
or die(mysql_error()); 
header("Location: accindex.php");

}
```

I don't know what is the problem. first the user type his details, and this code will be check and update in mysql. but not function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is backwards. By putting the `!` operator before `empty()` you're saying "if this variable is not empty". This is the opposite of what you want.

change:

```
if (!empty($_POST["fullname"]))
```

to:

```
if (empty($_POST["fullname"]))
```

Do this for all of your checks using `empty()`.

[Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [red box](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

**You are also wide open to [SQL injections](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174)**

Comment: I changed, but again not function :S

Answer (score 3):

Change `!empty($_POST['...'])` to `empty($_POST['...'])`.

Right now you are saying: if `fullname` is **not** empty, then return an error "fullname is required".